# Should I do this?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, c++11, buffer

```
void Clients::SetFog(char* fog)
{
  char Buffer[45];
  sprintf(Buffer, "d %s", fog);
  CMD(ID, SV_CMD_RELIABLE, Buffer);
  RtlZeroMemory(Buffer, sizeof(char));
}
```

My question is; I'm unsure how Buffers, well chars and int type variables are handled when defined within a function. As you notice I Zero it from memory, I do this with almost all my functions that have defined types just to keep memory clean, the type of app I'm building and the platform it's for I cannot debug that deep / peek into memory.

Comment: Why use a function call to set one byte to zero?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not zeroing Buffer's memory fully

```
RtlZeroMemory(Buffer, sizeof(char));
```

zeroes only first byte because sizeof(char) is 1

Second, your code is not safe because strlen(fog) may exceed length of your Buffer (which is 45)

And third you question is not clear. What do you mean asking " I'm unsure how Buffers, well chars and int type variables are handled when defined within a function". The general answer is that are handled in thesame way as if they were defined NOT within function. May be you can clarify your question?

Comment: Their will be no buffer overflow for fog, what made you assume it would reach a larger length? it's not from client input.

Comment: By the way, byte size of char is 4.

Comment: In C/C++ sizeof(char) is by definition 1, the standard says so.

Comment: @SergioPotatoNoseAllegretti the two most common errors in real C++ programs are resource lifetime (such as dereferencing invalid pointers, failing to `delete` a pointer) and buffer overflows.  What made someone assume a function that takes a `char*` without a length and stuffs it into a fixed sized buffer without any checks might overflow?  Because millions of programs have exactly that error in them.  In order to prevent that error, you'd have to audit every use of that function from now until end of lifetime of that code with the knowledge that the buffer has to be no more than 42 long.

Comment: @SergioPotatoNoseAllegretti I said "MAY exceed" because in the code you provided there is no check that it doesn't. And sizeof(char) is 1 in C/C++ as it was already said here.

Comment: @SergioPotatoNoseAllegretti Plus, if you sure that it is 4 then code still is not zeroing all 45 chars of Buffer. Because even 4 is still less than 45